# Android AR Core Exception during latest FLP api client construction. Falling back to legacy

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality

i am trying to use a AR Core [library](https://github.com/appoly/ARCore-Location) i followed all instruction from library instruction on how to use but its not working as expected i am getting **following error:**

```
2021-02-11 18:02:56.641 18165-18165/? E/example.dmodul: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-02-11 18:02:57.246 18165-18165/com.example.dmodule E/ARCore-LocationProvider: Exception during latest FLP api client construction. Falling back to legacy: com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates [class com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest, interface com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener]
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates [class com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest, interface com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener]
```

**My gradle**

```
....
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0"
implementation "com.google.ar.sceneform:core:1.17.1"
implementation "com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.17.1"
implementation 'com.github.appoly:ARCore-Location:1.2'
```

Example from library is working fine because its build with older version of android but i need to use this library for latest android version..i am searching from last 5 days but no luck also tried to contacting library author please help me thanks :)

Comment: any solutions??

Comment: this gets me crazy..

Comment: @RanjithKumar & aguagu, see the below answer, hope it will work for you.

Comment: @KamlendraPandey thanks. will update you after tested

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, actually, you have missed mentioning **GMS** classpath in the build.gradle of the project root.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

You can use the latest version accordingly.